# Confusion about require, require_relative, include in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

Please correct me if anything below is wrong.

1. My understanding is that I can use `require 'gemname'` in spec_helper.rb
2. Can I use `require` without any path for files in lib directory in spec_helper.rb ?
3. I never use `require_relative` in spec.helper.rb.
4. I need to use `require`, `require_relative` in lib/myfile.rb

Q. When do I need to use `include` in lib/myfile.rb ?

### Update

Sample structure

```
.
./ChangeLog.rdoc
./data
./data/msdata2013.xls
./data/msdataparts.xls
./Gemfile
./Gemfile.lock
./lib
./lib/correlation.rb
./lib/Irtest.rb
./lib/subcorrelation
./lib/subcorrelation/subjects.rb
./lib/subcorrelation/version.rb
./lib/subcorrelation.rb
./LICENSE.txt
./Rakefile
./README.rdoc
./spec
./spec/spec_helper.rb
./spec/subcorrelation_spec.rb
./subcorrelation.gemspec
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes you can require a gem in spec_helper.rb
2. Depends on you lib directory structure, if it is flat, you don't need to specify paths rspec looks in the lib directory by default
3. Require relative would only search for files relative to the spec_helper.rb, which might not be right as it rspec looks up files in the lib directory
4. You might need to lookup docs on [require](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require) and [require_relative](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative)

[`include`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-include) is used to include Modules in ruby

Answer (score 0):

Generally you will use require for gems in this situation, these should not need a path.

require_relative will require a path in your situation and should be placed in whatever file you need to use another file in. (if you're writing tests, the files with the things you are testing need to be listed via require_relative in the test file)

Include (and extend) pertain to modules and as far as I can tell for what you're doing you don't need them.